# clear cell content that contains NON- dollar values AND align cells that contain dollar values

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone have any ideas on achieving what I am trying to do? The goal is to get the rows to look like rows 27 through 32. I've been deleting the cells manually so far. I'm really hoping

1. for some kind of formula that'll read across the rows (range) and result in just the cells with dollar values

or

2. for some kind of macro/vba that'll achieve the same/similar result

[image]

Comment: Did you import csv (txt) into Excel?

Comment: copy and paste table from pdf that was OCR'd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs on the active sheet.

```
Sub RemovedNonDollarCells()
Dim r As Long, rows As Long
Dim c As Long, cols As Long, cv As Long
Dim arr()
Dim n

With ActiveSheet
    With .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
        rows = .Row
        cols = .Column
    End With
    arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rows, cols)).Value
    
    For r = 1 To rows
        cv = 0
    For c = 1 To cols
        n = arr(r, c)
        arr(r, c) = ""
        If n <> "" And IsNumeric(n) Then
            cv = cv + 1
            arr(r, cv) = n
        End If
    Next
    Next
    
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rows, cols)) = arr
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Is this applied to entire active sheet or select cell range?

Comment: I get an "Can't execute code in break mode" popup when applying it to a fresh sheet with data

Comment: It looks at the whole sheet.  For breaks, open the vb editor to see where it's breaking.  Sometimes it breaks on its own because VBA has turned into an ugly orphaned child of microsoft.  If that's the case, try this:
1. Press "Debug" button in the popup.
2. Press Ctrl+Break twice.
3. Hit the play button to continue.
4. Save the file after completion.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim arrRes(), rRng As Range
    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    r = 0
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        ' Get userange size
        iCol = .Columns.Count
        iRow = .Rows.Count
        ' array to store dollar values
        ReDim arrRes(1 To iRow, 1 To iCol)
        For Each rRng In .Rows
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
                If Left(rCell.Text, 1) = "$" Then
                    ' Debug.Print rCell.Address
                    arrRes(r, c) = rCell.Text
                    c = c + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        ' write array to cells
        .Offset(iRow + 2, 0).Value = arrRes
        ' Overwrite the data in same range
        ' .Value = arrRes
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Update**

Loading data into array to improve efficiency.

```vb
Sub demo2()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
    Dim arrData()
    arrData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        c = 1
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            rrData(i, j) = Trim(rrData(i, j))
            If Left(arrData(i, j), 1) = "$" OR IsNumeric(rrData(i, j)) Then
                arrData(i, c) = arrData(i, j)
                c = c + 1
            End If
            If j > c - 1 Then arrData(i, j) = ""
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Overrite data
    'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = arrData
    ' Output on new sheet
    Sheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arrData), UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrData
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this applied to entire active sheet or select cell range?

Comment: It is for Activesheet. You dont have to select data range.

Comment: Just tried it and it did not remove anything on a fresh sheet with data

Comment: What does `fresh sheet` mean?

Comment: ah new excel tab with just the data

Comment: Ohhh actually, I just scrolled down below. It made the new set of data under the original, not replace it. That works too!!! My eyes were looking on the left or right or some kind of replacement, ty ty ty!!

Comment: It's easy to replace the original data if needed.

Comment: I added an option to overwrite original data range.

Comment: Yes. and remove comment marker on `' .Value = arrRes`

Comment: Uh oh, I think the additional options to replace has got it to do nothing now. Can we revert back to the way it was before the add to replace? I get error popup of "run-time error '13 ':

Comment: Use the code in my reply w/o any changes.

Comment: I removed the module and re-inserted it and now it is doing nothing. Did I break it on my side? When I click on it this time, it gives me the spinning blue wheel as if it is still thinking and then it does nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure. Create a new workbook, paste your data, insert module and code, try it again.

Comment: Created a new workbook and it gives me the spinning blue wheel as if it is still thinking, freezes up excel as non-responsive, then and then it does nothing after wards .

Comment: The debug is highlighting this row "        .Offset(iRow + 2, 0).Value = arrRes"

Comment: How many data rows on your worksheet? You could paste some rows (eg. 100) and test the code. It is easy to identify the root cause. btw, `$15` is a Text or a number with format.

Comment: Could be less than 10 but no more than 200. Typically less

Comment: I don't think there is performance bottleneck w/ 200 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255419/discussion-between-lowell-and-taller-excelhome).

Comment: So it works when I recreate a new workbook with the example that you've used in your image response. But it doesn't seem to want to work consistently with larger data sets

Comment: How large? Do u prefer to overwrite the original data or keep result in a new area? I'll update the code.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: demo2()

It ran really quickly, didn't touch the data, BUT did create a new blank worksheet

Comment: It depends on what's the data from pdf. I have updated the code which is compatible with 15.00 / $15.00 and extra space.